# Line break in a <div>

Tags: html, css

I have this code and i want to have the “Links:” above the link but it stays on the same line. Does anyone know how to get them on their own line?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  color: white
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(img/bbground.jpeg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="lols" { text-align: center; }>
  <h1>Links:</h1><br>
  <a style="color:white; font-family:verdana;" href="https://bobjoerules.github.io/DarkMode-sheet" title="Home"><img src="img/darkmode sheet.png" alt="DarkMode-sheet-logo" width="192" height="108"></a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: If i make a div inside the div the image messes up to an image I used previously ```div:nth-child(1) { background-image: url(img/oksssssssssssssss.png); background-size: cover; background-position-x: center;
}``` also im using js for this ```const parallax = document.getElementById("parallax"); const lols = document.getElementById("lols"); window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){  let offset = window.pageYOffset; parallax.style.backgroundPositionY = offset * 0.7 + 'px'; lols.style.backgroundPositionY = offset * 2 + 'px'; })```

Comment: Have you tried `flex-direction: column;`? Remove the `<br>`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon like this ? ```<div id="lols" { text-align: center; flex-direction: column; }>```

Comment: No. You have CSS code. Put the CSS declaration in your CSS. `{ text-align: center; }` is completely meaningless in the middle of your `<div>` tag. Remove it.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+css+put+flex+items+vertically) of [How to vertically order the elements inside a flex container?](/q/57763579/4642212).